# codenameone UnsupportedClassVersionError: javafx/scene/media/MediaException has been compiled by a more recent version

Tags: codenameone

...of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I have moved from a Windows to an Ubuntu machine and am arranging all the projects. A bit difficult all of it but have got through for all of it with the exception of my CodenameOne project, which is firing this exception when launching the simulator in Netbeans 8.0.2.

The designer is not working either.

I am running JDK 1.8 (OpenJDK)

Can anybody hint me on what could I try next?

Answer (score 1):

In short, OpenJDK8 is not supported by the CN1 simulator because it doesn't include JavaFX.  You need to use Oracle's JDK8.  OpenJDK11 is, however, supported, as it is able to use JavaFX11 (which is now not part of the JDK).